# Drop down menu without affecting current hover effects

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

So currently here: http://pixphoriad.haneuri.net/header.php
I have a link hover effect on the top five links that I snagged online somewhere.

What I want to do is add a smooth css drop down menu from the "Resources" link but when I tried to play with it, nothing worked. I don't understand a whole lot that's going on with that current code in regards to that hover, and I'd like the link hover to stay the same, just have a drop down menu with links when hovered over.

Comment: use ul li tag under resources and apply css for that or provide any jsfiddle..ty

Comment: So the initial Resources link doesn't need the ul or li tags?

Comment: did not get your point? but in your nav bar under resource menu use ul li and then change the css of them..or there might be better solution so please provide jsfiddle so we can give best answer..

Comment: as @Leothelion mentioned, use `ul/li` tags for the menus. And when you want a submenu, in the li, us another ul/li for submenus. Check this tutorial: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: @lolka_bolka,  yup i told her/him and thanx for the link..i forget to add..:)

Comment: What I meant, was do I need to put the ul tag around the resources link, or under it? If I have to put it around it, is it possible to not give it any styles so that the initial hover affect isn't affected?

Comment: no you have to put ul li tag under the resources link..please check that link which loka bolka provided. and you have to apply css for ul li and it wont changes current css of resources link..but first do read those point in link..

Comment: I just used that tut, I think I got it figured out. Thanks guys :)